# How to find a reverse of the square which has o and x

Tags: python

I have got a square like this:

```
xoooo 
oxooo 
ooxoo 
oooxo 
oooox
```

And I am trying to reverse the pattern.
This is the code I have tried thus far:

```py
    size = int(input("Size of the square: "))
    
    for i in range(size):
        line = ""
    
        for j in range(size):
            if i == j:
                line += "x"
            else:
                line += "o"
    
        print(line)
```

Please help me to find out how to reverse the pattern of the above square to look like this:

```
oooox
oooxo
ooxoo
oxooo
xoooo
```

Comment: "And I am trying to reverse the pattern" What does this actually mean? What is the rule that tells you how to get from the input to the output? What should happen, for example, if the input is not square? If it does not have the same length on each line? If there are different symbols?

Comment: If you have that data in a file, then you can use `reversed()` over a list of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your problem:

In your `for` loop, you keep accidentally reassigning `line` as `""`. In order to keep lines rather than reassigning and losing it is to keep it outside the `for` loop.

Also, I recommend adding a "\n" to `line` after each iteration of i so that the lines are separated if you were to print them out.

```py
size = int(input("Size of the square: "))
line = ""
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        if i == j:
            line += "x"
        else:
            line += "o"
     line+="\n"
print("line")
```

As for getting it backwards, try:

```py
size = int(input("Size of the square: "))

line = ""
for i in range(size):
    
        for j in range(size-1,-1,-1):
            if i == j:
                line += "x"
            else:
                line += "o"
        line+="\n"
print(line)
```

This prints and appends it out backwards.